# The right way to do multiple MongoDB operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

If I need to perform two or three different operations on a few collections, is there a better way than chaining together `find/update` operations?  For example:

```
db.collection('contactinfos').findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: ObjectID(contactID) },
  { $set: { sharedWith } }
).then(response => {
  db.collection('users').update(
    { _id: { $in: sharedWith.map(id => ObjectID(id)) } },
    { $addToSet: { hasAccessTo: contactID } },
    { multi: true }
  ).then(response => {
    db.collection('users').update(
      { _id: { $in: notSharedWith.map(id => ObjectID(id)) } },
      { $pull: { hasAccessTo: contactID } },
      { multi: true }
    ).then(response => {
      return res.send({ success: true });
    }).catch(err => {
      logger.error(`in updating sharing permissions for ${contactID} by user ${_id}`, err);
      return res.status(400).send({ reason: 'unknown' });
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    logger.error(`in updating sharing permissions for ${contactID} by user ${_id}`, err);
    return res.status(400).send({ reason: 'unknown' });
  });
}).catch(err => {
  logger.error(`in updating sharing permissions for ${contactID} by user ${_id}`, err);
  return res.status(400).send({ reason: 'unknown' });
});
```

It just seems messy and there has to be some better way of doing it.  Furthermore, if there is an error after the first `findOneAndUpdate` that prevents the other `update`s from running, then there will be inconsistent data across documents.  The documents contain ID references to other documents for faster lookup.

Also, is there a way to catch all errors within a chain of promises?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your callback hell I can see you do not use `response` argument of `.then()` method anywhere. If you do not need results of one query to perform another, consider using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method:

```
const updateContactInfo = db.collection('contactinfos')
    .findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: ObjectID(contactID) }, 
        { $set: { sharedWith } }
    );
const updateUsers = db.collection('users')
    .update(
        { _id: { $in: sharedWith.map(id => ObjectID(id)) } }, //hint: use .map(ObjectId) instead.
        { $addToSet: { hasAccessTo: contactID } },
        { multi: true }
    );
const updateUsers2 = db.collection('users')
    .update(
        { _id: { $in: notSharedWith.map(id => ObjectID(id)) } }, //hint: use .map(ObjectId) instead.
        { $pull: { hasAccessTo: contactID } },
        { multi: true }
    );

Promise
    .all([updateContactInfo, updateUsers, updateUsers2])
    .then((values) => {

        const updateContactInfoResult = values[0];
        const updateUsersResult       = values[1];
        const updateUsers2Result      = values[2];

        return res.send({ success: true });

    })
    .catch((reason) => {

        logger.error(`msg`, reason);
        return res.status(400).send({ reason: 'unknown' });

    });
```

`Promise.all()` will continue executing following `.then()` only if all the promises do resolve, otherwise it'll fall into the `.catch()` method. As of error handling, you can easily chain multiple `.catch()` methods, which is nicely explained [here](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/chainable-catches-in-a-promise).

If you cannot have any data inconsistency, either:

1. Get some SQL database with transactions  (easier solution)
2. Look into [MongoDB Two-Phase Commit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/)

And if it is acceptable to happen, let's say once per 1kk times, do include checking it's consistency within your app's logic.